# Creating a new tag on a question that wasn't asked by me

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

Just a little question about tagging.

If I create a new tag by editing a question wasn't asked by me, the tag is considered as created by the question's owner or created by me?

My question is related to the [Taxonomist badge](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a new tag on questions asked by others and got the Taxonomist badge for it so it is considered created by you.

Comment: Thanks you again.